# Input loses focus, but doesn't blur, when user scrolls page or clicks outside textbox

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

So I have a form in a phonegap/cordova (2.0) application.  It is on a page inside an iframe and is behaving how it should in most cases.  The problem comes when you click on an input field and then either accidentally touch outside of the input or scroll the page at all.  The input still has the blue carrot showing that it has focus and no blur event is fired in javascript, but you can't edit the input.  Refocusing the textbox doesn't fire the focus event and also does not allow you to enter test.  You have to focus another element (which blurs the input) and then refocus it.

Is there a way to prevent the input from psuedo-losing focus?  I don't want to blur the input when the user scrolls, that will cause the keyboard to close and lead to other issues (we had a problem before where clicking outside an input would close the keyboard and would preform a second click on mouseup while the page was moving... we managed to finally get rid of it though).

Comment: Haven't been able to find a successful basic case.  I thought it might be jquery.validity or mobiscroll... but then it happened on a page that didn't have them.  After I finish this other task I'm working on I'll try to get a test page to generate the problem and see if I can post it here.

Comment: Ok, so more testing shows that it happens when mobiscroll is added.  The page without mobiscroll (that's in a different iframe...) only experiences the problem if you view the page with mobiscroll first.  So it's propagating the problem to the whole project after you view a page with mobiscroll.  I'll probably just talk my boss into using type='date' as default and falling back to mobiscroll only when the user is using iOS version less than 5.0.